# ClassNotFoundException thrown from Maven when compiling JUnit tests

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a Maven project that **compiles fine on my Mac** - but I just moved it to my Windows 10 PC for the first time, and am seeing odd compilation issues for my JUnit tests. The failure is:

```
stringContainingEmojiWithTrailingSpaceIsDetected(com.myapp.EmojiUtilTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType
        at emoji4j.EmojiUtils.removeAllEmojis(EmojiUtils.java:241)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

This appears to be a transitive dependency of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kcthota</groupId>
    <artifactId>emoji4j</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As a `mvn dependency:tree` contains:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myapp ---
[INFO] com.craigotis.myapp:myapp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:58.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.kcthota:emoji4j:jar:5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]       +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]       \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
```

But I can't seem to understand why the class is not found - if I check my Maven repository, the JAR exists:

```
~\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.7.0\jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar
```

As does the `JavaType.class` class in the JAR.

Adding the `jackson-databind` dependency manually to my POM does not seem to make a difference.

What would cause this class to not be found by Maven during test compilation, **on this machine?**

**Edit:** Further, if I run Maven with debug logging, I see:

```
[DEBUG] test classpath classpath:
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\projects\myproject\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\projects\myproject\target\classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\6.0.5\mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.4.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.4.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.4.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.4.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-dbcp2\2.0.1\commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-pool2\2.2\commons-pool2-2.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.7\log4j-api-2.7.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.7\log4j-core-2.7.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\58.1\icu4j-58.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\kcthota\emoji4j\5.0\emoji4j-5.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.7.0\jackson-core-2.7.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.7.0\jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.7.0\jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\lambdaj\lambdaj\2.3.3\lambdaj-2.3.3.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.1\hamcrest-all-1.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
[DEBUG] provider classpath classpath:
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-junit4\2.12.4\surefire-junit4-2.12.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\Craig\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.12.4\surefire-api-2.12.4.jar
```

Which seems to clearly list the Jackson JARs.

Comment: Is it all the output of mvn dependency:tree goal ? If it is not, can you post it please ?

Comment: Thank you but no potential conflict inside. How do you run your tests ? Wrapped by an IDE or by command line ?  If you go to command line and you enter `mvn clean install -DskipTests` and then `mvn test`. You have the same problem ?

Comment: @davidxxx Yes, same problem - the `clean install` finishes fine, but the `test` fails with the same error.

Comment: *...Adding the jackson-databind dependency manually to my POM does not seem to make a difference.* Just to confirm you added `<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>`? and what version did you use there? Also did you try using `mvn clean install -C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color me very confused. I renamed my `jackson` directory in my `.m2` folder and let Maven download new dependencies, and the error went away.

The sizes of the JARs are different, despite the insides seeming the same. **New** on the left, **old** on the right:

[image]

Comment: Got corrupted, probably

Comment: Yep. Just seems odd that Maven can't compare SHA1 files with what's in the central repository and detect that it has a corrupt copy.

Comment: `-C, --strict-checksums `(Fail the build if checksums don’t match)
If you are concerned about security, you will want to run Maven with the -C option. Maven repositories maintain an MD5 and SHA1 checksum for every artifact stored in a repository. Maven is configured to warn the end-user if an artifact’s checksum doesn’t match the downloaded artifact. Passing in the -C option will cause Maven to fail the build if it encounters an artifact with a bad checksum.

Comment: Thanks - I find it odd that's not enabled by default, and would require a flag to _disable_ it.